# Fill in the blank help - present perfect or *past simple?

Tags: grammar, past-tense, present-perfect

> Stephen Hawking was known the most because he ______ many things while living with this terrible disease, ALS.

a. accomplished 
b. has accomplished

it is tricky because his accomplishments are still influencing other people.

I think it's A because he died recently, and also I recalled the Grammar rule which talks about past simple + past progressive interruption (e.g While I was eating, John came)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stephen Hawking is now, sadly, deceased, so it's not appropriate to use the present perfect to describe any of his actions. In this case use the *simple past* (not the simple present):

> Stephen Hawking is widely known because he **accomplished** many things while living with his terrible disease.

However, you may use the present perfect to talk about his accomplishments, since those continue to have an effect:

> Even after his death, Stephen Hawking's accomplishments **have influenced** many physicists.

Side note:  "Was known the most" is grammatical but juvenile.  Better expressions:

> Stephen Hawking was the **most well-known**  ...
>
> Stephen Hawking was **widely-known** (for/as) ...
>
> Stephen Hawking **gained renown** (for/as)...
>
> Stephen Hawking was **famous** (for/as) ...

As well as many other variations.

Comment: Thank you very much Andrew, crystal clear. I have another question, can I ask you here?

Comment: @GhassanSaeed  Yes, if it's related to this one.  Otherwise please post it as a separate question?